# Unable to run enable.py when trying to install dragonfly

Tags: python-dragonfly

I am trying to install dragonfly, i got natlink installed, without problems.
But when i try to run enable.py i keep getting this error:

```
C:\NatLink>python enable.py        
Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "enable.py", line 400, in <module>
        def unregister_natlink_module(base=natlink_macro_system_path()):
      File "enable.py", line 177, in natlink_macro_system_path
        return os.path.join(find_natlink(), "MacroSystem")
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
        result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
        if len(p) > 1:
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Python version: 
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32.
How do i proceed from here?

Comment: Where is enable.py from? I can't find it in the Dragonfly or Natlink folders, and I've got them both installed.

Comment: http://dragonfly.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html search for Daniel Rocco

Comment: Those westga.edu instructions are really old. The current Natlink instructions are better for installing Natlink. http://qh.antenna.nl/unimacro/installation/installation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Rocco's enable.py was for Natlink, not Dragonfly, and is old. To install Dragonfly, download the .zip from Github, and then open a command prompt in the directory you unzip it in and run "python setup.py install". More detailed instructions [here](http://explosionduck.com/caster/install/dragonfly.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNAsV4pcnEA).

Comment: thank you, little confusing its still in de offcial dragonfly documentation. This cleared up some stuff

Comment: python setup.py install --record=installfiles.txt

incase you want to delete them later ;D